# Bad results at Google speed test

Tags: php, image

So I have a Pinterest like website that allows users to upload images. When the image is uploaded I'm resizing it with this code:

```
imagejpeg($image, $hey, 10);
```

This resizes my images to an average of 180KB. If I go lower than 10 in my code the images look really bad. Google gives a grade of 30 in the speed, and I don't understand why? am I resizing the images in the wrong way? The dimensions are kept the same since on image click a popup opens that shows the real image dimensions

Comment: saying your images are a certain byte size is useless information. a 1x1 180kb image is ludicrous. a 10000x10000 180kb image is pretty dang small. a score of 30 when loading 500+ 180kb images is pretty good. score of 30 loading one single 180kb image is bad.

Comment: They are for now 2448X3263 or the opposite. Depends if the image is portrait or landscape. This is images from an iPhone, probably it will change with different users upload.

Comment: then 180kb is quite reasonable. You've taken a ~24megabyte raw bitmap and compressed it to 0.77% of its original size.

Comment: The score was for loading 7 images. I'm using also LAZY LOAD. At pingdom.com I got a score of 77